# PHP print() Arabic string

Tags: php, apache, arabic

When I try and execute this code to print out an Arabic string: `print("إضافة");`  I get this output: `Ø¥Ø¶Ø§ÙØ©`.  If I utf8_decode() it I'll get `?????`.    I have "AddLanguage ar" in my apache configuration but it doesn't help.  How do i print out this Arabic string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also set your page language to utf8 eg:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and then see it if worked. If that still doesn't work, go and check this out, it is complete solution for the arabic language using PHP:

http://www.ar-php.org/en_index_php_arabic.html

You may want to check out this too:

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2875.html

Answer (score 8):

It might be necessary to indicate to the browser which charset you are using -- I'm guessing it's UTF-8.

IN order to achive that, you might try putting this portion of code at the beginning of your script, before any output is generated :

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

`[`utf8_decode`][1]` will try to decode your string from UTF-8 to latin1, which is not suited for Arabic characters -- hence the `'?'` characters.

Comment: Thanks,  your method works great,  but the other guy was first so he got the mark :).

Comment: No problem :-) Import thing is that your problem is solved :-)

Comment: @PascalMARTIN thank you, after searching for hours, your reply helped me solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You may want to set

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

in your `php.ini`. [Default charset](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) directive instructs the server to produce correct content type header.

You can also do it in runtime:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check your browser font if it has Arabic support. Stick to common fonts like Arial Unicode and Times New Roman.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

First: Add by the beginning  of HTML page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

second:
if you are using AJAX encode data using **encodeURIComponent**

Third:
First line of your PHP page should be

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and decode the data sent to PHP using **urldecode**

Regards,

Comment: also,if you are using oracle as DB use the following connection string: $connect=oci_connect($UserName,$Password,$db_name,'AL32UTF8');